# Programming a recursive FFT with Mathematica

Tags: recursion, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to program a FFT using a recursive function in *Mathematica*, though my program is not getting me anywhere at the moment. Could you say what's wrong with it and what I can do to make it work?

My program is the following: (We assume that a is a list of size $2^s$ for some integer $s$)

```
 FFT[a_] :=

  (n := Length[a];
  If[n == 1, Return[a],
  f := Exp[2 I Pi/n];
  o := 1;
  b := Drop[a, {1, Length[a], 2}];
  c := Drop[a, {2, Length[a], 2}];
  d := FFT[b];
  e := FFT[c];
  For[k = 0, k < n/2, k++,
  y[k] := d[[{k}]] + o e[[{k}]];
  y[k + n/2] := d[[{k}]] - o e[[{k}]];
  o = o f]
  Return[Table[y[i], {i, 1, n}]]])
```

Comment: While I can see there are some issues with your program, I was wondering if you had thought about using the built-in function [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) instead?

Comment: I have, thanks, but it's more of a programming exercise than anything else.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself or did you translate it from some other language?  Is this a homework exercise?  If you wrote the code yourself, I'd study the basic of Mathematica a bit before embarking on such a project.  There are just too many un-Mathematica-like and inefficient constructs here to go through explaining what's wrong with each of them.  For a start, learn about the difference between `:=` and `=`, don't use `For` (look up `Do` and `Table`), don't use `Return` when it's not needed, and localize variables with `Module`. Also check your `;`s.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wrote it from what I understood mathematically, that's probably why it seems so artificial. That's not homework, I'm just trying to get better at programming with Mathematica, but I guess I'll spend more time on the basics. Cheers, T.

Comment: Also, check your brackets, they are not balanced

Comment: I just edited the code, thanks

Comment: I wrote a particularly compact recursive FFT implementation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169654).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using this as an excuse to learn to code in Mathematica, I'll try to help with that in mind. Sometimes I find it nice to design "from the top down", document from the top down, split in many small functions with no state, and go testing them "from the bottom up". As you gain confidence, you will perhaps use coarser functions, and not test every little thing.

I'll improvise some "testing framework" for this answer. It's just what came to mind, nothing particularly recommended.

Say we have a function `f`, and we know that `f[2]` must return `3`, and `f[4]` must return `9`. Then we write `test[f] ^= Inactivate@{f[2] -> 3, f[4] -> 9};`, and when we want to run those tests, we do `runTest[f]`. We just need to define something like

```
runTest[sym_] := 
 Inactive[TestReport][
   test[sym] /. (x_ -> y_) :> Inactive[VerificationTest][x, y]] // 
  Activate
```

Ok, let's start.

So, what do we want to do? An fft. Let's say the fft that's equivalent to Mathematica's `Fourier` with `FourierParameters->{1, -1}`.

```
mmafft=Fourier[#, FourierParameters->{1, -1}]&;
```

Tests serve as documentation too. Let's write some fft pairs

```
test[fft] ^= Inactivate@{
    fft[{1}] -> {1},
    fft[{1, 0, 0, 0}] -> {1, 1, 1, 1},
    fft[{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}] -> {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1}
    };
```

It is standard MMA convention to have your function names start with lowercase.

The `fft` of a list with a single element is an identity function. Let's write that

```
fft[{v_}]:={v};
```

Done. Now, if the list is longer, a generalization of your approach, divide and conquer, would be to split it, apply the `fft` to each part, and merge the results. Let's write that

```
fft[l_List]:=fft/@split[l]//merge
```

Done. Now, we need to tell Mathematica what split and merge are. Let's start with `split`.

A possible way of splitting, that is consistent with your proposal, is to split "downsampling" to the least integer factor of the list length. So, if the list has 2^s elements, this will always be 2. Let's write some examples

```
test[split] ^= 
  Inactivate@{
   split[{1}] -> {{1}}, 
   split[{1, 2}] -> {{1}, {2}}, 
   split[Range@6] -> {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}
 };
```

Good. Let's code this

```
split[l_List]:=split[l, nextFactor[l]];
```

This definition outsourced the task of knowing in how many pieces to split it. Now, the actual splitting

```
split[l_List, numParts_Integer]:=l~Partition~numParts//Transpose
```

This is just a way out of many.

Our `split` definition relies on a function `nextFactor` that takes a list and returns the number of pieces to split it into. For example

```
test[nextFactor] ^= Inactivate@{
    nextFactor[Range@10] -> 2,
    nextFactor[Range[3 7 2]] -> 2,
    nextFactor[Range[3 7]] -> 3};
```

Let's code this

```
nextFactor[l_List] := FactorInteger[Length@l][[1, 1]]
```

We've hit bottom. `nextFactor` is totally defined. Let's test it. `runTest[nextFactor]` gives success. Good.

Now, `split` is defined. Let's test it. `runTest[split]` gives success. Good.

Time for `merge`. This function takes a list of ffts from time shifted and downsampled signals and merges them adding them up.

```
merge[ffts_List] := 
 upsampledFft[Length@ffts] /@ ffts // timeShiftedFfts // Total
```

The fft of an upsampled signal is simply repeating it that many times

```
test[upsampledFft] ^= Inactivate@{
    upsampledFft[2]@{1, 2, 3} -> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3},
    upsampledFft[3]@{1, 5} -> {1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5}
    };

upsampledFft[k_Integer][l_List] := 
  PadRight[l, k Length@l, "Periodic"];
```

`runTest[upsampledFft]` suggests its all good

`timeShiftedFfts` time shifts each fft a different amount

```
timeShiftedFfts[ffts_List] := MapIndexed[timeShiftedFft, ffts];
```

Shifting an fft is multiplying by an exponential that turns as many times in the whole length of the list as the number of shifts.

```
timeShiftedFft[fft_List, {index_}] := timeShiftedFft[fft, index - 1];
timeShiftedFft[fft_List, n_] := With[{len = Length[fft]},
  fft Exp[-I 2 Pi n/len Range[0, len - 1]]
  ]
```

I didn't make tests here because I was lazy and they weren't too straightforward, but now we should at least test it with some inputs and see if the output makes sense, starting from `timeShfitedFft`, up to `merge`.

`merge[{mmafft[{1, 3, 5}], mmafft[{2, 4, 6}]}] // Chop` gives the same as `mmafft[Range@6]`, so far so good.

All is done. `runTest[fft]`. Successsss. This can be made more efficient, but it usually is a good idea to not get crazy about that until you know you need it. Complexity seems fine. Compared to a naive implementation.

```
naiveFft[l_List] := 
     Length@l /. len_ :> l.SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> 
     Exp[-I 2 Pi (j - 1) (i - 1)/len], len {1, 1}]

r = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2^16];
BenchmarkPlot[{naiveFft@# &, fft@# &}, Take[r, #] &, 
 PowerRange[2^2, 2^16, 2], "IncludeFits" -> True, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for showing us the new debugging tools.

Comment: +1. Really nice explanation. Plot added.

Comment: @RunnyKine thanks for the plot :)

Comment: @Rojo, You're welcome and thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Rojo, might be a dumb question, but what does ^= do?

Comment: @Sascha, it's like `=` but the definition is attached to the symbol being tested instead of `test`. This means that if you `Clear[split]`, for example, `test[split]` is cleared too.

Comment: @Rojo this no longer works for me in 10.1: `runTest[sym_] := 
 Inactive[TestReport][
   test[sym] /. 
    Verbatim[Rule][x_, y_] :> Inactive[VerificationTest][x, y]] // 
  Activate
test[add] ^= Inactivate@{add[{1, 2}] -> 3};
add[l__] := Total[l];
runTest[add]` fails

Comment: @M.R. I just tried your code on Linux, 10.1, clean kernel, and it worked. Weird

Comment: @Rojo I'm on OSX 10.10.3